# Terraform on Azure cloud - VM name and Data disk name are not aligned

Tags: azure, terraform, azure-virtual-machine

I have created VM and added Data Disk to be, however there is one issue.The VM name and data disk name DO NOT align. Please refer to the screenshot below.

[image: NXTPREPAOS-1 Machine Disks]

[image: NXTPREPAOS-1 Machine Disks]

[image: NXTPREPAOS-5 Machine Disk]

The terraform code is below:

```
resource "azurerm_managed_disk" "tf-mdsk-cluster" {
  count                = 5
  name                 = "${var.ax_base_hostname}-${count.index+1}-DATADISK-1"
  location             = "${azurerm_resource_group.tf-rg-cluster-aos.location}"
  resource_group_name  = "${azurerm_resource_group.tf-rg-cluster-aos.name}"
  storage_account_type = "Standard_LRS"
  create_option        = "Empty"
  disk_size_gb         = "1024"
}

resource "azurerm_managed_disk" "tf-mdsk-2-cluster" {
  count                = 5
  name                 = "${var.ax_base_hostname}-${count.index+1}-DATADISK-2"
  location             = "${azurerm_resource_group.tf-rg-cluster-aos.location}"
  resource_group_name  = "${azurerm_resource_group.tf-rg-cluster-aos.name}"
  storage_account_type = "Standard_LRS"
  create_option        = "Empty"
  disk_size_gb         = "1024"
}

resource "azurerm_virtual_machine" "tf-vm-cluster-aos" {
  count                 = 5
  name                  = "${var.ax_base_hostname}-${count.index+1}"
  location              = "${azurerm_resource_group.tf-rg-cluster-aos.location}"
  resource_group_name   = "${azurerm_resource_group.tf-rg-cluster-aos.name}"
  availability_set_id   = "${azurerm_availability_set.tf-as-cluster-aos.id}"
  network_interface_ids = ["${element(azurerm_network_interface.tf-ni-cluster-aos.*.id, count.index+1)}"]
  vm_size               = "${var.ax_vm_size}"

  storage_data_disk {
    name            = "${element(azurerm_managed_disk.tf-mdsk-cluster.*.name, count.index+1)}"
    managed_disk_id = "${element(azurerm_managed_disk.tf-mdsk-cluster.*.id, count.index+1)}"
    create_option   = "Attach"
    lun             = 0
    disk_size_gb    = "${element(azurerm_managed_disk.tf-mdsk-cluster.*.disk_size_gb, count.index+1)}"
  }

  storage_data_disk {
    name            = "${element(azurerm_managed_disk.tf-mdsk-2-cluster.*.name, count.index+1)}"
    managed_disk_id = "${element(azurerm_managed_disk.tf-mdsk-2-cluster.*.id, count.index+1)}"
    create_option   = "Attach"
    lun             = 1
    disk_size_gb    = "${element(azurerm_managed_disk.tf-mdsk-2-cluster.*.disk_size_gb, count.index+1)}"
  }
}
```

I have **changed** the **managed disk block**

***FROM***

```
managed_disk_id = "${element(azurerm_managed_disk.tf-mdsk-cluster.*.id, count.index+1)}"
```

***TO***

```
managed_disk_id = "${element(azurerm_managed_disk.tf-mdsk-cluster.*.id, count.index)}"
```

But that has not solved the mystery, any idea as to how to resolve it?

Comment: if you remove all `+1` in codes, apply again, what name will you get?

Comment: +1 in managed disk block or storage_data_disk block? Index starts from 0, I want it to start from 1 hence I use +1 as an offset.

Comment: I adjust the expression. My question is, if remove all `+`, will you get the same index across OS disk and data disks in same stack?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there is something you have misunderstand and make it a wrong setting. When you create the managed disk, you set the index with `count.index+1`. Then the data name will has the number {1,2,3,4,5} with the index {0,1,2,3,4}. And when you create the VM and add managed disk in it. You set the index in the `storage_data_disk` also as `count.index+1`. So when the index is 1 of the VM, the disk number will be 2.

You can change the index in the `storage_data_disk` into `count.index`. And it will work as you want. The `azurerm_virtual_machine` will like this:

```
resource "azurerm_virtual_machine" "tf-vm-cluster-aos" {
  count                 = 5
  name                  = "${var.ax_base_hostname}-${count.index+1}"
  location              = "${azurerm_resource_group.tf-rg-cluster-aos.location}"
  resource_group_name   = "${azurerm_resource_group.tf-rg-cluster-aos.name}"
  availability_set_id   = "${azurerm_availability_set.tf-as-cluster-aos.id}"
  network_interface_ids = ["${element(azurerm_network_interface.tf-ni-cluster-aos.*.id, count.index+1)}"]
  vm_size               = "${var.ax_vm_size}"

  storage_data_disk {
    name            = "${element(azurerm_managed_disk.tf-mdsk-cluster.*.name, count.index)}"
    managed_disk_id = "${element(azurerm_managed_disk.tf-mdsk-cluster.*.id, count.index)}"
    create_option   = "Attach"
    lun             = 0
    disk_size_gb    = "${element(azurerm_managed_disk.tf-mdsk-cluster.*.disk_size_gb, count.index)}"
  }

  storage_data_disk {
    name            = "${element(azurerm_managed_disk.tf-mdsk-2-cluster.*.name, count.index)}"
    managed_disk_id = "${element(azurerm_managed_disk.tf-mdsk-2-cluster.*.id, count.index)}"
    create_option   = "Attach"
    lun             = 1
    disk_size_gb    = "${element(azurerm_managed_disk.tf-mdsk-2-cluster.*.disk_size_gb, count.index)}"
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much Charles for your explanation, it is now all clear.
The essence is we don't have offset twice. More importantly once we offset in creation then there is no need to offset it again in VM.

Helped me solved other issue as well.

Cheers